# Sun JDK 1.5 cannot dereference error with generics

Tags: java, generics, java-5

We have a class hierarchy similar to this one:

```
public class TestDereference {
 private static MainInterface mi = new MainInterfaceImpl();

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(mi.getSubInterface().getField());
 }
}

interface MainInterface {
 <T extends SubInterface> T getSubInterface();
}

interface SubInterface {
 Field getField();
}

class Field {
 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Hooray!";
 }
}

class SubInterfaceImpl implements SubInterface {
 Field f = new Field();

 public Field getField() {
  return f;
 }

}

class MainInterfaceImpl implements MainInterface {
 SubInterfaceImpl si = new SubInterfaceImpl();

 public <T extends SubInterface> T getSubInterface() {
  return (T) si;
 }
}
```

The interfaces actually have more than one implementation but that's not the problem. Compiling this with the Eclipse compiler or Java 1.6 works just fine (as seen on [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/owQC4)). But if I try to compile this with Java 1.5 (which is one of the requirements of our project) gives the following error:

```
TestDereference.java:12: test.SubInterface cannot be dereferenced
                System.out.println(mi.getSubInterface().getField());
                                                     ^
```

Also note that it doesn't happen with JDK 1.6 using `-target 1.5` either, only with JDK 1.5

The only cases when this error occurs that I found on the web are related to doing things like this:

```
double d = 2.0;
d.toString();
```

where it's obvious what the problem is.

But it my case it should work, since it's clear that `getSubInterface()` returns a `SubInterface` implementing class that definitely has the `getField()` method.

So is this a compiler bug? And what options do I have besides doing `mi.<SubInterface>getSubInterface()` every single time (which works, but since Eclipse doesn't mark this as an error, most people on the team forget do it, and most of them use only JDK 1.6 so they don't notice it when compiling with maven/cmd line either)?

Comment: What exact versions of the JDK are you using? (5 and 6?)

Comment: 1.5.0_22 and 1.6.0_20 (according to `javac -version`)

Comment: What happens when you try the compiler flag `-source 1.5` or if you set the Eclipse Compiler Compliance level to 1.5 instead of 1.6?

Comment: What happens if you do `System.out.println(mi.<SubInterface>getSubInterface().getField());`?

Comment: Eclipse is already set to 1.5, and setting -source 1.5 (with or without -target 1.5) on javac 1.6 makes no difference (it compiles just fine).

Comment: @dacwe If I use it like that it works like it should including in JDK 1.5, it prints `Hooray!` The problem is it's cumbersome and shouldn't be needed as shown in JDK 1.6 and Eclipse which compile just fine without specifying the type parameter.

Comment: Yes, seems that the problem is solved in JDK6 see my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5003431

Option one:

```
SubInterface si = mi.getSubInterface();
si.getField();
```

Option two:

```
mi.<SubInterface>getSubInterface().getField()
```

Comment: So I guess if I'm stuck with 1.5 there's not much I can do apart from these two options. I was hoping for something a bit more elegant I guess, but this will have to do.

Comment: I accepted your answer for also giving the link to the bug report, which showed it was only fixed in 1.6

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a bug that was fixed in Java6.

Rewriting your main method as follows will make things work in both Java5 and 6:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SubInterface subInterface = mi.getSubInterface();
    System.out.println(subInterface.getField());
}
```

It seems Java5 needs the assignment to properly derive the type `T`, even though it's already declared to extends `SubInterface`. Java6 handles this correctly and doesn't need the additional assignment.